# Radio buttons are rendering on top of rest of form

Tags: django, bootstrap-4

I'm using vanilla bootstrap with Python on Django. I've configured a form with radio buttons, however the buttons render on top of the fields as shown in the screenshot below.

I've notice that Django puts the radio buttons into a list and I thought that could be the cause, so I tried using CSS to disable the  tag but the radio buttons still float on top just without the list bullets.

[image]

Forms.py

```
class MerchantGroupForm(forms.Form):
    DO_WHAT_CHOICES=[('merge','Merge'),
                    ('update','Update')]

    #do_what = forms.ChoiceField(choices=DO_WHAT_CHOICES, widget=forms.RadioSelect(attrs={'class': "custom-radio-list"}))
    do_what = forms.ChoiceField(choices=DO_WHAT_CHOICES, widget=forms.RadioSelect)

    merge_merchantgroup = forms.ModelChoiceField(required=False, queryset=MerchantGroup.objects.all().order_by('name'), empty_label="Merge with")
    name = forms.CharField(required=False)
    default_ledger = GroupedModelChoiceField(required=False, queryset=Ledger.objects.all().order_by('coa_sub_group__name','name'), choices_groupby = 'coa_sub_group')
    disable_AI = forms.BooleanField(required=False, label='Disable AI')
```

```
      <form action="/monzo/merchantgroups/update/799/" method="post">
                
                
                <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="ZWtsz3JDsnUtu1mj6NO3SDlBuyJyEpDgbZUDC6elfTPK2DCwWevD2BpirSZJOhiM">
                
                
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="id_do_what_0">Do what:</label>
                        <ul id="id_do_what" class="custom-radio-list form-control">
    <li><label for="id_do_what_0"><input type="radio" name="do_what" value="merge" class="custom-radio-list form-control" required id="id_do_what_0">
 Merge</label>

</li>
    <li><label for="id_do_what_1"><input type="radio" name="do_what" value="update" class="custom-radio-list form-control" required id="id_do_what_1">
 Update</label>

</li>
</ul>
                        
                        
                    </div>
                
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="id_merge_merchantgroup">Merge merchantgroup:</label>
                        <select name="merge_merchantgroup" class="form-control" id="id_merge_merchantgroup">
  <option value="" selected>Merge with</option>

  <option value="203">ATM</option>

  <option value="799">Amazon</option>

  <option value="200">Post Office</option>

  <option value="201">Virgin Media</option>

  <option value="202">www.modelsport.co.uk</option>

</select>
                        
                        
                    </div>
                
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="id_name">Name:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="name" value="Amazon" class="form-control" id="id_name">
                        
                        
                    </div>
                
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="id_default_ledger">Default ledger:</label>
                        <select name="default_ledger" class="form-control" id="id_default_ledger">
  <option value="">---------</option>

  <optgroup label="Accounts">
  <option value="20">Jacks Account</option>

  <option value="32">Jacks Monzo</option>

  <option value="21">Janes Account</option>

  <option value="126">Janes Monzo</option>

  <option value="22">Joint Account</option>

  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Bills">
  <option value="7">Council tax</option>

  <option value="6">Electricity &amp; Gas</option>

  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Cash">
  <option value="23">Jacks Float</option>

  <option value="24">Janes Float</option>

  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Food &amp; Home">
  <option value="8">Basic food</option>

  <option value="9">Coffee &amp; Snacks</option>

  <option value="11">Home Supplies</option>

  <option value="10">Take away</option>

  </optgroup>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Property">
  <option value="19">Property</option>

  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Purchases">
  <option value="31">Computer &amp; Electrical</option>

  <option value="30">Hobbies</option>

  <option value="29" selected>Toys</option>

  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Reserves">
  <option value="27">Profit &amp; Loss Accounts</option>

  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Taxation">
  <option value="5">Income tax</option>

  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Taxation">
  <option value="25">Tax Liability</option>

  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Travel">
  <option value="17">Public Transport</option>

  <option value="18">Taxis</option>

  </optgroup>
</select>
                        
                        
                    </div>
                
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="id_disable_AI">Disable AI:</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="disable_AI" class="form-control" id="id_disable_AI" checked>
                        
                        
                    </div>
                
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
            </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the screenshot you showed have template the previous `.html` code then **Django does nothing** because you don't use Django form to render your form. It's just  a plain HTML/Bootstrap form.

This is how to use [Django Form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/3.2/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually).

**Also** if you want to Group radios on the same horizontal row with Bootstrap then you can add `.form-check-inline` to any `.form-check` as [Bootstrap inline radio button](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/forms/#inline) page says.

```
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="merge" 
    value="merge">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="merge">Merge</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="update" 
    value="update">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="update">update</label>
</div>
```

**NB :** I think that your first `.form-group` is not well structured.
You can visit [Bootstrap form](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/forms/) to do it fine.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the form-control class did the trick. According to Bootstrap docs this class is only for certain fields, guess radio is not one of them.